# how to determine the characteristic function

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

**Problem 2.24** 
from Digital Communications, 5th Edition by John Proakis, Masoud Salehi

---

$Y=\sum_{i=1}^nXi$

where the $Xi, i = 1, 2, . . . , n, $ are statistically independent random variables with

$Xi = \begin{cases}
1\ with\ probability\ p \\
0\ with\ probability\ 1−p \\
\end{cases}$

Determine the characteristic function of Y

thank you .

Answer (score 1):

First identify that $X$ is Bernoulli distributed.

So we have $P(X=1) = p = 1 - P(X=0)$, and by using the formula for $E[h(x)]$

you get that $E[e^{itX}] = \sum e^{ikt} P(X=k) = P(X=0) e^{0} + P(X=1)e^{it} = 1-p + pe^{it}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I need to apply $\sum_{i=1}^nXi$ ? 
I can't do this part :(

Comment: Not that $X_i$ are independent so $E[e^{itY}] = E[e^{itX_1}] \cdot ... \cdot E[e^{itX_n}]$ @citius

Comment: finally I found solution but I don't understand .
https://image.ibb.co/de396a/Capture.png 
can you explain it ?
thank you .

Comment: if $A,B$ are independent, then $E[AB] = E[A]E[B]$ and $e^{A+B} = e^{A}\cdot e^{B}$. @citius

Comment: another question why $Xi$ change to $X$ when pull Pi out of bracket

Comment: @citius Because they are identically distributed.

Comment: when it's come to X , Pi i=1 to n will multiply X by X n times that made $(\ )^n$ right ?